# Why does router.push reload / re-render the pages with next.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js

In my component, I have:

```
    return (
        <TouchableRipple onPress={() => router.push(`/conversations/${props.item.id}`)} style={{ marginBottom: 50 }}>
            <Surface style={{ height: 200, flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-start', borderRadius: customTheme.roundness, elevation: customTheme.elevation }}>
```

It goes to `/conversations/1`, but rerenders the entire page. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide 2 parameters to the push for it not to reload:

```
router.push(
  `/conversations/query-param=${props.item.id}`,
  `/conversations/${props.item.id}`
)
```

The `query-param` is the named parameter used in conversations

Comment: No dice - still does a rerender

Comment: @Shamoon You could try to preserve network tab information and the console. See if anything fails to load or causes an error.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using getInitialProps inside your conversations page, then it will refresh the page for you you need to use https://github.com/fridays/next-routes

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies with the next router giving a new instance on every change. You probably have the following code:

```
const myPage = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  
  return (...);
```

Essentially you are changing the router object as router.query now contains the updated url params. It seems that the router will give back a completely new instance of the router. Hence your functional component is updated because one of it's external dependencies changed. I too am looking for a solution to stop that behavior.

Quick fix: Move the expensive computations to a component and call that from your page. Then on your page add a quick cache to query (such as `const routerPush = useMemo(() => router.push, []);` and pass that into the component.

Answer (score -3):

Did you try with brackets instead?

```
<TouchableRipple onPress={() => router.push(`/conversations/[props.item.id]`)} style={{ marginBottom: 50 }}>
```